# QuickBooks UK Edition Change VAT Field

Tags: quickbooks

I am trying to change the VAT field in QuickBooks UK. I want to to say E instead of S. I am sending this XML, however, the VAT field fails to change. Am I using the wrong field?

Here is my XML:

http://pastebin.com/QWmB7jKF

I am using SalesTaxCodeRef - FullName as E

In my response, I notice that the SalesTaxCodeRef Full Name is S and tax has been included:

```
<SalesTaxPercentage>17.50</SalesTaxPercentage>
<SalesTaxTotal>6.50</SalesTaxTotal>
```

Do I need to change another field on top of SalesTaxCodeRef - FullName to change the VAT?

I notice that this happens with any code I use, such as EGS. I tried using the ListID field, however, it had no effect. Perhaps there is a setting in QuickBooks UK to change the VAT field?

Comment: Post the full XML response you get back from QuickBooks.

Comment: Thanks. I made the change.

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of qbXML? 3.0 is about 10 years old now. I would try 8.0 or higher and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks. I tried 8 and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a newer version of qbXML. You are using:

```
<?qbxml version="3.0"?>
```

Which is geared towards QuickBooks 2004.

More than likely, if you use a newer version of qbXML you'll have better luck. Try 8.0 or higher.

```
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
```